# How to programmatically add site to "Site access" in Google Chrome Extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Is it possible to programmatically add any URL to the "Site Access" from my extension?
Install type - from uncompressed extension directory.

The client wants to easily reinstall the extension for testing without manually adding dozens of sites to the Whitelist.
He does not wants to working without whitelist.

I tried use host_permissions:

```
    "host_permissions": [
        "https://testsite1.com/*",
        "https://testsite2.com/*"
    ]
```

But when I call chrome.permissions.GetAll(), a list appears, the first element is the <all_urls> template:
[Response for chrome.permissions.GetAll()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XH1Zm.png)

And nothing happens in extension details page. Only selected option "On all sites".

How it should look like:
[Properly view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vnXrK.png)

Comment: You probably have a content script that runs on all URLs. It counts as site access. Remove it and use chrome.scripting.registerContentScripts. See also [optional permissions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/permissions).